# cant delete file directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to delete an image directory after cleaning all the files in the directory. The problems is cleaning the files in the images directory works because the same method is used to clean directory before image upload. But deletion of the image directory itself is not working. I don't know what am missing.

this is the code sample

controller

```
@GetMapping("/categories/delete/{id}")
public String deteleCategory(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    
    try {
        service.delete(id);
        String proDir = "../pro-images/" + id; //directory folder path
        FileUploadUtil.removeDir(proDir );//delete image directory  
        
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "The profile ID " + id + " has been deleted");
    } catch (ProfileNotFoundException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

service class method to delete directory

```
    public void delete(Integer id) throws ProfileNotFoundException {
        
        Long countById = repo.countById(id);
        //if(countById.equals(null) || countById.equals(0)) {
        if (countById == null || countById == 0) {
            throw new CategoryNotFoundException("Could not find any category with ID " + id);
        }
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
```

method to clean image directory before deletion

```
public static void cleanDir(String dir) {
    Path dirPath = Paths.get(dir);
    
    try {
        Files.list(dirPath).forEach(file -> {
            if(!Files.isDirectory(file)) {
                try {
                    Files.delete(file);
                }catch(IOException ex) {    
                    LOGGER.error("Could not delete file: " + file);
                }
            }
        });
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not list directory: " + dirPath);
    
    }
}
```

removes image directory

```
public static void removeDir(String dir) {
    cleanDir(dir);//delete all files in the directory(folder)
    Path dirPath = Paths.get(dir);
    try {
        Files.delete(Paths.get(dir)); //deletes directory itself (folder)
        
    }catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not remove directory: " + dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error? The way you are handling the IOException hides the stacktrace from your logs. You should print it to see the real error, e.g. instead of `LOGGER.error("Could not remove directory: " + dir);` use `LOGGER.error("Could not remove directory: " + dir, e);` This way the exception stacktrace will be printed and you should see the error cause (and post it here to help you further)

Comment: Nothing is showing in the console after trying LOGGER.error("Could not remove directory: " + dir, e);

Comment: I just found out that directory will not delete whiles the application is still running. But the directory get deleted after stopping the application. I don't know if it is the version of the OpenJDK is making it behave that way. I am using OpenJDK 16.